# PHP game tile map images

Tags: php, dictionary, tile

i have tile based map

```
$map = '<table border="1">';
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $map .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
        $map .='<td width="50" height="50"'.$bgcolor.' align="center" valign="center">
        <div id="move_'.$Tx.':'.$Ty.'">('.$Tx.','.$Ty.')</div>
        </td>'; 
    }
    $map .= '</tr>';
}
$map .= '</table>';

echo $map;
```

Every cell has different 10x10 pixels image .

```
 _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
```

I need that new image apears after every 4th cell, because my images are 40x40 pixels. But

```
          1.image X|2. image X 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
           |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
1.image Y  |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
           |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
           |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
           |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
2.image Y  |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
           |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
           |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

I hope that you undestand me, my english is pretty bad
Omerimuni

Comment: Sorry, your question is _not_ clear currently. What size are your images, 10x10px or 40x40px?

Comment: i need that after every fourth cell appears new image. new images are 40x40 but cells are 10x10

Comment: Try to make an image to show what you are trying to explain, because it is not clear yet.. Are you going to append more cells to your table?

Comment: i have 200 x 200 grid

http://www.upload.ee/image/2816734/GRID.png

Answer (score 2):

He is trying to tilemap with HTML tables by having a 40px image overlaid onto 4x 10px table cells.

This is really not the best way to do what you're trying to do as it will create. The main reason for this is that HTML does not like having pictured stacked over tables and the elements will not layer correctly.

Try looking up tilemaping using HTML5's `canvas`. you really dont need the HTML table at all and in the end it will just make your life harder.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use an image `<map>` and 1 big image if it never changes.